# What is ECMAScript Editon 5.1, and what is it for?

Tags: javascript

I just stumbled upon this (while browsing the ECMA web-site):

http://www.ecma-international.org/activities/Languages/Draft%20Standard%20ECMA-262%205.1%20edition.pdf

It says [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39-M.htm) that edition 5.1 is going to replace edition 5 in June 2011.

My question is: What is this edition 5.1 and why is it being published? (Is something wrong with edition 5?)

**Edit:** I found this:

> ECMAScript 5.1 is a maintenance
>   revision of the ECMAScript 5
>   specification. It corrects technical
>   and editorial errors and its content
>   is identical to the proposed ISO
>   edition of the ES5 specification. This
>   is intended to be the final draft,
>   subject to approval by TC39 and the
>   completion of the ISO standardization
>   process.

Source: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php

---

**Update:**

As [JavaScript Weekly](http://javascriptweekly.com/) posted in today's newsletter, ECMAScript 5.1 has been ratified and has been made available for download on the main page for ECMAScript here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://www.wirfs-brock.com/allen/posts/39

> The ISO edition of the ES5
>   specification incorporates a number of
>   editorial and technical corrections
>   including those listed in the current
>   ES5 errata.

In other words, ECMAScript 5.1 is a revision of 5.0 that corrects some errors in the document itself. As mentioned later on in the article:

> Keep in mind that this is only a
>   maintenance revision of the ES5
>   specification.  It contains no new
>   language or library features.  TC39 is
>   continuing its longer term work on
>   “ECMAScript Harmony” which is intended
>   to be the next version to include any
>   new features.